# Can we access Storage Location for Azure Recovery Service Vault/Azure Backup Service

Tags: azure, azure-backup-vault

Azure Recovery Service Vault gives an option to use either LRS or GRS storage redundancy. Is there a way to access the storage location that the backup data gets written to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, we maintain the storage accounts and take care of automatic storage management wrt growing and moving them around etc, so as a end user you can't access those storage accounts directly. You can only retrieve data using the management operations such as restore on a backed up item.